# Flutter iOS Error : Invalid `Podfile` file: no implicit conversion of nil into String

Tags: flutter

I just upgraded my flutter version to the latest stable version 2.0.1. But when I build iOS there is an error like below:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: XXXXXXXX
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳

    [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: no implicit conversion of nil into String.

     #  from <my-project-path>/ios/Podfile:57
     #  -------------------------------------------
     #      unless File.exist?(copied_framework_path)
     >        FileUtils.cp_r(File.join(cached_framework_dir, 'Flutter.framework'), copied_flutter_dir)
     #      end
     #  -------------------------------------------

    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:318:in `rescue in block in from_ruby'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:312:in `block in from_ruby'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:50:in `instance_eval'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:50:in `initialize'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:310:in `new'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:310:in `from_ruby'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:276:in `from_file'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:205:in `podfile'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:160:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Exception: Error running pod install
```

I have been looking for a solution in few days but i have not found a solution, is there anyone who can help?

thank you,

Comment: can check with anydesk ??

Comment: @JanviPatel can you explain more clearly?